# which is the best way to insert values in mysql via python scripts in a loop

Tags: python, mysql

I have the backup script like below

```
for f in os.listdir(path)
  // do backup
```

Now i want to insert in mysql values like foldername , date , size etc

This is mysql script

```
sql = "INSERT INTO pythontest(name, \
       name2, name3) \
       VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" % \
       ('Mac', 'Mohan', '')
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()
```

Now i am not sure whether insert full code in for loop or make a function of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"insert full code in for loop or make a function" - nothing we must decide for you. It is your snippet taken out of the context and only you can make a decision if encapsulating your code into a method is making or sense or not....this is really up to you .